# Android: Understanding os sendBroadcast(Intent i)?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Iam new to android. I could understand the concept of Broadcast Receivers, but i couldn't understand the concept of sendBroadcast(Intent i).. My main doubt is who will listen to this sendBroadcast.

```
public class OOVOOActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public static int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        addShortcut();
 }

    private void addShortcut(){  
        Intent shortcut = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

        // Shortcut name
        shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));  
        shortcut.putExtra("duplicate", false);  // Just create once

        // Setup current activity shoud be shortcut object 
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(this.getPackageName(), "."+this.getLocalClassName());  
        shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setComponent(comp));  

        // Set shortcut icon
        ShortcutIconResource iconRes = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.search);  
        shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconRes);  

        sendBroadcast(shortcut);  
    }
```

I have few questions to ask,

1. In the above code there is no **toast message** is used, But if i
   run the app i could see the toast msg.. Plz explain how it is coming
   and also tell me how to hide those toast msg.
2. U could see **sendBroadcast(shortcut);** , basically who will listen to this broadcast.

Plz clear my doubt. Thank U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> U could see sendBroadcast(shortcut); , basically who will listen to this broadcast.

Some other app or apps. No app might receive this broadcast. 999 apps might receive this broadcast. That is up to the user and the developers of those other apps.

In this case, you are assuming that there are one or more apps on the device that will respond to a `com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT` broadcast. Please note the `com.android`. This means that this `Intent` action is not part of the Android SDK. `com.android` is used for pieces of the Android environment. As it turns out, this `Intent` action is not documented, meaning that it may or may not work on all devices and Android OS versions.

> Plz explain how it is coming

Other developers, besides you, can write code that displays `Toast` messages. They can even write code that displays `Toast` messages in response to a broadcast `Intent`. It turns out that your test environment contains such code, possibly in the `com.android.launcher` application.

> also tell me how to hide those toast msg

You don't.

Comment: every app can sign up to receiving this intent when it's fired.